# Install Windows on a second disk using VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, installation, sysprep

I've got a machine with Windows 7 (and an OEM license for it), and I've now bought a new hard drive which I will be using as the system disk.

Here's the deal. I would like to reinstall windows on this new hard drive without having to shut down my computer.

I'd like to fully prepare my new installation before I start using it; all software and configurations *apart from* drivers, which I can install later.

My question is: Is it possible to install Windows on my second drive using VMWare or VirtualBox? Does the hardware configuration have to match, or would it be possible to install it and then use sysprep it before it's time to use it on the physical hardware?

Anyway, the idea here is that I want to install and configure my new Windows 7 installation, on a new drive, while I'm still working on my computer.